# how to check iptables status and allow ip in ubuntu

Tags: linux

how can check status of iptables in Ubuntu.service iptables status command is not working on my side so how can allow an ip address as i am not able to ssh to that machine.

Comment: this belongs on serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 3):

You can list the rules in iptables with `iptables -L -v`.

To enable a remote machine to access your local ssh server:

1. Check that your ssh server is listening on all interfaces
2. If the three chains listed are empty, make sure their policy is ACCEPT
3. If any of the chains has a policy other than ACCEPT, add a new rule to the right chain with something like, for example: `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`. Check man iptables for details
4. Make sure you are not trying to access an unroutable address (e.g. a private ip address)
5. Check that there's no other firewall in the middle
6. Try connecting with telnet to the ssh port, see if it connects at all!
7. Come back here :)